# My SO purchased an extended warranty and I need advice on our legal standing

Tags: contract-law, civil-law, vehicle

My girlfriend recently bought a brand new 2020 KIA Stinger from Koons KIA in VA. We are located in PA and have thus taken the car to a local KIA dealer.

Unfortunately, she purchased an extended warranty service through them that, according to them, provided oil changes, brake changes, and certain additional wear and tear above the limited warranty provided through KIA.

Koons KIA expressed that the warranty would work through any KIA or FORD dealer. We took the car to the local KIA dealer for an oil change and initially had zero problems.

After picking it up it was paid for through the warranty and all seemed fine. Just now, at 5:00pm 12-31-2020, she received a call from explaining to her that the warranty company will not cover "synthetic" oil.

The problem here is that Koons KIA expressly stated that the warranty was for this car. Specifically mentioning the oil and also other expensive parts such as the brake pads and rotors, which are Brembo brakes, as a selling point for the warranty that she has purchased. I expect that anytime she takes the vehicle in she will have the same problem.

What are your thoughts behind the meaning of the contractual language? This is not a question for specific legal advice, but for legal minds postulating the meaning behind the contractual language.

Thank you

[image: Contract]

[image: Maintenance]

Comment: Is synthetic oil required for this Kia model?

Comment: Yes, synthetic oil is required for this car.

Comment: Then I agree with the answer that the warranty for this car should include that oil.

Comment: Why was this question closed? Is it too close to asking for legal advice or something?

Comment: This question clearly seeks specific legal advice, to the point of pasting images of a specific contract, using a title that explicitly says "I need legal advice" and referring to a specific individual's circumstances. This is textbook RSLA and should have been closed immediately, not answered or upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The exact terms of the warranty are decisive. The term "*oil changes*" is unqualified, and therefore it encompasses all types of oil that are appropriate for the covered car. Once the warranty is purchased, the company is not allowed to qualify or restrict the scope of that contract.

The company's mention of oil changes and other features as a selling point reinforces the argument that the parties' intent at the formation of the contract did not exclude synthetic oil.

In case of doubt, feel free to reproduce the relevant clause(s) and I will edit this answer if the contract language changes the parties' legal position.

Comment: My apologies, the contract does include a caveat for "synthetic oil" that was not communicated to her. A commenter has recently communicated that including "oil changes" would imply synthetic oil as anything otherwise in a new car would void the original mfg warranty.
If helpful, I can upload a picture of the contract with all personal info void.

Sorry for the lack of info.

Comment: The contract feels predatory in that manner, as it only includes a caveat for oil type, and this was never communicated to my SO. Meaning, this is something you must "upgrade" to, because it is not included in the purchase you have already made.

Further, the rest of the contract is ambiguous, inviting ancillary info to define the contract...

Comment: @skatmouth "*anything otherwise in a new car would void the original mfg warranty*". Yes, but the company will point out that the purchased warranty encompasses more than oil changes (brake changes, additional protection for wear & tear, etc). The statement "*the contract does include a caveat for "synthetic oil" that was not communicated to her*" is contradictory. If she signed that contract, from a legal standpoint she was duly informed. Feel free to elaborate on "*the contract is ambiguous, inviting ancillary info to define the contract*", but so far it seems that the company would prevail.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, have some courage to explain why. It might have been the same person who downvoted the question.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the answer should not have assumed that the summery of the coverage in the question included the full text of the contract, and specifically that "oil change" was unqualified. If it was, the answer seems good to me.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I think nobody with enough proficiency in contract law assumes that a summary includes the full text of the document it summarizes. My mention of "unqualified term" was intended to --and it evidently managed to-- direct the OP's attention to a key detail of the contract. Assessing "*as is*" the information an OP provides (which I did in the answer) is the opposite of incorporating unsupported or inaccurate assumptions.

Comment: Generally fair enough. I think I would hafe written something like  "**If** The term "oil changes" is unqualified,.." but the rest of the answer is good, and I have upvoted now.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Thank you again for all of your replies. Ambiguous in that none of the other boxes are checked and that KIA is not mentioned in the terms under "What this plan covers ... "

I've added the relevant docs, I also refer to the second document they added which expands on the coverage, including "change engine oil and replace filter"